# how to use data stored in a map to sort an array using std::sort() function in c++?

Tags: c++, sorting

i wanted to use a hash  map to sort a string on the basis of the values the map has.but i just could not find a suitable way..please help me find a way. 
so here is a c++ code that I wrote please help me how to write it better
i want to know how to use std::sort() by passing a data structure for sorting

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
unordered_map<char,int>m;
bool h(char a,char b)
{
    return m[a]<=m[b];
}
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        //unordered_map<char,int>m;
        for(int i=1;i<=26;i++)
        {
            char a;
            cin>>a;
            m[a]=i;
        }
        string s;
        cin>>s;
        sort(s.begin(),s.end(),h);
        cout<<s<<endl;
        //m.erase(m.begin(),m.end());
        //cout<<endl<<m.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: your code does not compilable. Please post a [MRE]

Comment: also what do you mean by "sort a string on the basis of the values the map has"? Please clearly state what you want to solve, what is the expected result and what errors and/or observable behavior you get.

Comment: What's the idea? Sort some letters based on arbitrary weights which are stored inside a hashmap? You could do a better job presenting the problem. It needs an input, expected output, actual output, and compilable code ... as already mentioned.

Comment: Didn't any of the answers help? In that case, can you clarify the question?

Answer (score 1):

Your [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) function does not fulfill the *strict weak ordering* requirement.

`return m[a] <= m[b];` should be `return m[a] < m[b];`

With that change, your program works correctly and sorts the `std::string` in the order your map holds. If you enter the characters `zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba` your `sort` will sort the `string` in reverse alphabetical order.

Suggestions:

- Read about [why you shouldn't include `<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h). Include the correct headers instead:

  ```
  #include <algorithm>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>
  #include <unordered_map>
  ```
- Try to avoid magic numbers like `26`. You can make your loop like this for the same effect:

  ```
  for(int i = 0; i <= 'Z'-'A'; i++)
  ```

  *1-26* and *0-25* (as the above loop produces)  will have the same effect.
- Avoid global variables such as `m`. You can make it local and refer to it in a *functor*, like a lambda.
- Read [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the commended out lines were what you were trying to get working.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "enter number of times" << endl;
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        unordered_map<char,int>m;
        cout << "enter 26 characters" << endl;
        for(int i=1;i<=26;i++)
        {
            char a;
            cin>>a;
            m[a]=i;
        }
        cout << "enter a string" << endl;
        string s;
        cin>>s;
        sort(s.begin(),s.end(), [&](char a, char b)
        {
            return m[a]<m[b];
        });
        cout<<s<<endl;
        m.erase(m.begin(),m.end());
        cout<<endl<<m.size();
    }
}
```